# Grunt for-loop on grunt.task.run with variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, gruntjs, command-line-interface

I'm currently trying to create a task in grunt sending parameters to run another task multiple times.

Here is my already functional single build task:

```
var country = grunt.option('country') || 'X0';
var product = grunt.option('product') || 'Y0';
var subdomain = grunt.option('subdomain') || 'Z0';

grunt.registerTask('build_home', [
    'sprite:publicProduct',
    'sprite:home',
    'uglify:home',
    'sass:home',
    'csscomb:home',
    'cssmin:home'
]);
```

So in my day to day, I would run the command:

```
grunt build_home --country=X0 --product=Y7 --subdomain=Z3
```

What I want now, is a task that would run all my possible predefined options:

```
grunt build_home_all
```

It would be something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('build_home_all', function() {

    var products = ['Y0','Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4','Y5','Y6','Y7','Y8','Y9'];
    var subdomains = ['Z0','Z1','Z2'];

    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) { 
        for (j = 0; j < subdomains.length; j++) {
            grunt.task.run('build_home --product='+products[i]+' --subdomain='+subdomains[j]);
        };
    };

    grunt.log.ok(['Finished.']);

});
```

I've already achieved this with grunt.util.spawn, but it kinda runned asynchronously and was forcing my cpu with all kinds of tasks running at the same time.

Comment: Instead of running the tasks in the for loop, you should push the tasks to an array that you generate in the for loop, and then run that array.

Comment: @theaccordance That's actually pretty useful and is part of the solution, but i still can't run something like `grunt.task.run('build_home --country=X0 --product=Y7 --subdomain=Z3')` as it displays `Warning: Task "build_home --country=X0 --product=Y7 --subdomain=Z3" not found. Use --force to continue.` it just doesn't identify the parameters.

Comment: You'll want to look at creating a custom task as an initializer for each build process and passing the options using `this.args`.  Your queued tasks will look like `build_home:X0:Y7:Z3` instead.  Reference: http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks#this.args

Comment: Okay I wrote out an answer, it might need some tweaking as I made a couple assumptions.  Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `grunt.task.run` method of calling tasks, you won't be able to pass arguments how you would normally using the CLI, but you can still pass arguments using colon-separated notation:
`build_home --country=X0 --product=Y7 --subdomain=Z3` => `build_home:X0:Y7:Z3`

Update your `build_home_all` task to the following:

```
function buildHomeAll() = {
    var products = ['Y0','Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4','Y5','Y6','Y7','Y8','Y9'],
        subdomains = ['Z0','Z1','Z2'],
        tasks = [],
        country = grunt.option('country') || 'X0';


    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < subdomains.length; j++) {
            tasks.push(['build_home',country, products[i],'subdomains[j]'].join(':'));
        };
    };
    grunt.task.run(tasks);

    grunt.log.ok(['Finished.']);
}
```

You'll invoke this function using `grunt build_home_all --country=X0`

Next, you'll need to modify your `build_home` task to account for the new way arguments can be passed in:

```
function buildHome() = {
    if (!grunt.option('country') {
        grunt.option('country', this.args[0] || 'X0');
    })
    if (!grunt.option('product') {
        grunt.option('product', this.args[1] || 'Y0');
    })
    if (!grunt.option('subdomain') {
        grunt.option('subdomain', this.args[2] || 'Z0');
    })

    grunt.task.run([
        'sprite:publicProduct',
        'sprite:home',
        'uglify:home',
        'sass:home',
        'csscomb:home',
        'cssmin:home'
    ]);
```

Lastly, expose the functions in your `gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.registerTask('build_home', buildHome);
grunt.registerTask('build_home_all', buildHomeAll);
```

Comment: I've managed to create the task and did almost exactly as you did. The difference is that I've set the option on to grunt.initConfig and changed it with grunt.config.set. Would there be any noticeable performance difference? Thanks a lot btw.